# When are the moderator elections?

Tags: support, moderation

Biology.SE [graduated](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/site-graduated) an hour ago and one of their posts had an answer stating about election.

> The most recent graduated site took somewhere like 2-3 weeks after the design post to graduate. There will be elections for moderators a few weeks after graduation. –  Mad Scientist♦

([link](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/hello-graduation-goodbye-moderator-privileges#comment3124_3032))

Its been a week for Chem.SE now, so should I expect it next week?
So when does it happen?

Related links:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators

[There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours, I'm afraid!

Comment: (what jonsca said)

Wow, their new design is amazing!

Comment: And I hope you two will remain @ManishEarth

Comment: @jonsca ^^^^^^^

Comment: A big update: Elections now live (to the future readers of this question)